# Mudar o nome de uma variavel usando Parametros de uma Função //Javascript

Tags: javascript

**Isso é apenas um exemplo:**

```
function myfunction(u)

e+"u" = 1
x+"u" = 1
o+"u" = 1

//ai chamando ela...

myfunction(1)

e1 = 1
x1 = 1
o1 = 1
```

**Teria como fazer isso ser válido ou fazer algo parecido?**

Comment: Não deu pra entender nada. Qual é o propósito? O código tampouco faz sentido.

Comment: Acho que o que você está procurando tem a ver com reflexão.
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex%C3%A3o_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: Esse código não funciona, é apenas um exemplo, eu quero que o valor do parametro junte com a variavel

Comment: Vocês está querendo concatenar o nome da variável com o argumento? Isso não é o ideal, nesses casos melhor usar array (existe o `eval` tb, não é recomendado) ou outra estrutura de dados, de toda forma, no seu exemplo exemplo você está concatenando com a string "u", não o argumento `u`.

Comment: e como eu faria isso?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript possui [objetos](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp), baseado em chaves e valores tal que acredito ser mais útil para o que está tentando fazer. Dessa forma, é possível adicionar *n* chaves, e depois recuperar de diversas formas. Baseado no seu exemplo:

```js
var meuObjeto = {}

function myfunction(u) {
  meuObjeto['e'+ u] = 1;
  meuObjeto['x' + u] = 1;
  meuObjeto['o' + u] = 1;
}

myfunction(1);
console.log(meuObjeto);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a variável window como escopo global e alterar a propriedade do objeto, ficaria algo como :

```
function myfunction(u){
  window['e'+u] = 1;
  window['x'+u] = 2;
  window['o'+u] = 3;
}

myfunction(1)
console.log(e1); //1
console.log(x1); //2
console.log(o1); //3
```